# set width of fixed div equal to that of parent width (which is declared as percentage)

Tags: html, css, width, css-position, sticky

I want to have the width of a `position: fixed` div (because I want it to be able independently of page scrolling) equal to the width of its parent ( a `td` element ).

However I cannot seem to achieve that. My current code is:

html:

```
<table style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
  <td id='tdLeft'>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  </td>
  <td id='tdRight'>
    fdsfsd
    <br>
    rfeoif jerofj eriof
    <div id='divFixed'>
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfaaasd, fdfsdss, 
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd, 
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#tdLeft, #tdRight {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#tdLeft {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
}
#tdRight {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: green; 
}
#divFixed {
    position: fixed;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 100px;
    width: inherit;
}
```

So the little black box should be as wide as the green `td` element.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpovqd4u/2/

a `position: sticky` position doesn't properly work (the width is correct) but it doesn't stay sticky due to more layers of wrapping divs on top and it's not also desirable due to lackluster browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can have what you want by replacing `fixed` with `sticky` but it will work perfectly in case the table is your only element as `sticky` position will not make the element to be fixed outside his containing block (parent element)

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
}

#tdLeft,
#tdRight {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#tdLeft {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

#tdRight {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

#divFixed {
  position: sticky;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="tdLeft">
      fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </td>
    <td id="tdRight">
      fdsfsd
      <br>
      rfeoif jerofj eriof
      <div id="divFixed">
        hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfaaasd, fdfsdss, 
        hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd, 
        hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the browser support for `position: sticky` is only 85% as of today.

Comment: It sort of works. In the actual page, the width is correct but the sticky part isn't working (while it is working here). In the actual page the table has even more wrappers on top of it.

Comment: @Armel 85% means that it's good to be used ;) I don't wait 100% to use a new feature, starting from 70% is very good for me

Comment: to whoever that downvoted, that is never a reason to downvote!!

Comment: @kukkuz probably someone lost his keys ;) (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/386331) no need to worry about one downvote.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Unfortunately not, there are more layers of wrappers and css and would be overly complicated to collect and show

Comment: @MIrrorMirror then it would also be complicated to give an accurate answer :)

Comment: Well, there is no support at all for IE. It depends who you are targetting, you are the only one who can decide ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: sticky` instead of *fixed*:

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
>   document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor
>   and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including
>   table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and
>   left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.
>
> Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

See demo below:

```css
#tdLeft, #tdRight {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-spacing: 0px;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 vertical-align: top;
}
#tdLeft {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
#tdRight {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green; 
}
#divFixed {
 position: sticky; /* CHANGED */
 border: 1px solid black;
 top: 100px;
 /*width: inherit;*/
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 90%; border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
  <td id='tdLeft'>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  fdsfsdfsd<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  
  </td>
  <td id='tdRight'>
    fdsfsd
    <br>
    rfeoif jerofj eriof
    <div id='divFixed'>
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfaaasd, fdfsdss, 
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd, 
      hahaha, fdsfsd, fsdfsd, fdsfds, fdsfsd, fdfsd
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```